# Behavior of rundeck workflow with "Stop at the failed step" and "Parallel strategy"

Tags: rundeck

Scenario: create rundeck workflow with 2 steps

- Step1
- Step2

Set option for "If a step fails" to "Stop at the failed step".
Set option for "Strategy" to "Parallel"

Assume Step1 and Step2 are long run process, which all 2 steps start concurrently execution. So I need to know with above setting, if Step1 has failed but Step2 is keeping running without complete yet.

Rundeck will fired failed result in main activity window immediately after Step1 failed, or waiting for Step2 finish running?

Is there any way to force rundeck to fired failed result in main activity after both Step1 and Step2 finish no matter what Step1 or Step2 have failed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's the default Rundeck behavior.

But, you can use the inline-script step ("Script" step) to do some script-fu.

The idea is to launch two tasks at the same time and report that the job is failed *after* both tasks are finished. I leave a job definition example, feel free to modify it.

Job definition example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>4e5e03b7-4d9d-404c-9ebe-7adbcc178d2f</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='true' strategy='parallel'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# just a simulation of two paralell task on bash
sleep 10; eco "first task"; status=$(echo $? &) # this task has a intentional error to test the script
sleep 20; echo "second task"; status=$(echo $? &)

# just for debug
echo "whole status is: $status"

# and depending of the result, the job fails (or not) *after* the two tasks
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>4e5e03b7-4d9d-404c-9ebe-7adbcc178d2f</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

The rundeck job always fails if the exit code is non-zero.